# Update state of active widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

Hello everyone and sorry for my English.

In general, I have 2 widgets, one is on the screen, the other is somewhere in the navigator. These are 2 different instances of the same widget. Tell me if there is a way to update the status of only the active widget, i.e. the one in the first navigator?

I googled it, but i didnt find anything

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Please add relevant code so that the community can understand your issue correctly.